# Interior and closure operators iterated

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and for arbitrary $A \subseteq X$ define a sequence of subsets of $X$ as follows: $A_0 := A$, be $A_{n+1}:= Int(A_n)$ (the interior of $A_n$ for $n$ even) and $A_{n+1}:= Cl(A_n)$ (the closure of $A_n$ for $n$ odd). May this sequence in general have infinitely many different elements? Is there a characterization of  those spaces in which the sequence stabilizes after finitely many iterations for every $A$?

Answer (score 1):

It always stabilises as $\operatorname{int} \overline{A}$ is regular open for any $A$, and $\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}$ is regular closed for any $A$. So after int cl int cl we’re back at int cl again, and also cl int cl int = cl int as well. So $A_4=A_2$ always (if I've counted the iterations correctly).

Comment: A small [note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/24.pdf) of mine about the Kuratowski 14 set problem, when iterating complementation as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a characterization for the spaces in which int cl int = cl int ?

Comment: @Alberto int cl int is open and will rarely be equal to cl int. Discrete spaces will obey it, maybe extremally disconnected spaces too.